# How to change Point options when using Map?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, options, map

I want to change the point size of the points I am plotting in the code below, but wherever I place the PointSize[] option it doesn't like it.

[image: Plotting points in table pvals]

The code is part of a larger program, which generates a two graphics, one of the stereographic projection of the Hopf bundle and another image corresponding to point of the 2-sphere each fibre is mapped to. I will include the rest of the code below.

[image: The reset of the program]
[image: The graphics Produced]

Comment: try `Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Map[Point,pvals]}]`?

Comment: ... or `Graphics3D[Map[{PointSize[Large], Point@#}&, pvals]]`

Comment: In this case, your problem is a simple one, but when you ask a question, please post the Mathematica code instead of an image. Posting the code lets others copy and paste it rather than typing it from scratch.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: `Point` also takes *a list* of points. if all your points can be styled the same, then the easiest way would be to flatten the list and style all of them at once: `Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.02], Red, Point[Flatten[pvals, 1]]}]`.